# run netty server in separate thread

Tags: java, netty

I have the next app for running my application:

```java
// class Server

public static void runServer(int port) {
  var boss = new NioEventLoopGroup()
  var worker = new NioEventLoopGroup()
  var serverBootstrap = new ServerBootstrap()
  try {
    serverBootstrap.group(boss, worker)
    // initilizers  
  } finally {
    // shutdown
  }
}
```

and also I have an entry point class:

```java
// initialize logging
Server.run(some_port);
// other code in the application
```

The trouble is: when I run my netty server, I do not initialize other code (after `Server.run`). How to do it correctly in netty?
My base idea is: run in a separate thread, like:

```java
new Thread {
  public void run() {
     Server.run(some_port);
  }  
}
```

is it correct? or I missed something from Netty approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `runServer` method should most likely return the `Channel` that you bind too. In this case you should also be able to run more code after it.